# C#/Java programmer learning C++ again. Project file structure?

Tags: c++

As the question states, i am a C#/Java programmer who is interested in (re)learning C++. As you know C#/Java have a somewhat strict project file structure (especially Java). I find this structure to be very helpful and was wondering if it is a) good practice to do a similar structure in a C++, b) if so, what is the best way to setup it up?

i know there is the basic 'headers' and 'source' folders, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the structure of java projects quite nice. I do it like this (root is the root directory)

*root/include/foo/bar/baz.hpp* becomes

```
namespace foo { 
namespace bar {
    // declare/define the stuff (classes, functions) here
} } // foo::bar
```

in code.

I keep the source in

*root/src/foo/bar/baz.cpp* . If i have some stuff that is not exposed to the outside, i put it into a *detail/* directory and namespace. I keep the makefiles at *root/*.

Answer (score 1):

> a) (is it) good practice to do a similar structure in a C++,

One way to find out would be to download a few open source projects and look at their file structure.

In my experience, the build tool used really ends up dictating the file structure.  If it's a bit of a pain to have lots of subdirectories with your build tool of choice then you won't have lots of subdirectories.

> b) if so, what is the best way to set it up?

That depends on your build/dev environment.  I personally use vim and Linux file tools, so I set this all up by hand.  Somebody using Eclipse or Visual Studio probably has a number of wizards to work from.

Comment: Visual studio does it all for you, no work involved at all. But I think you are stuck with what you see.